# Changing settings of Bitcoin-Qt on Mac

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I am using Bitcoin-Qt on my Mac under Mac OS 10.8.3. Everything is working fine but when I want to change any settings in the settings menu, it will never remember my new settings. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. You should perhaps report it on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues?state=closed).

Comment: I will try to re-install it, maybe it will solve the problem.